# Comparing values of type Text with values of type True/False

Tags: dax

I have a data column of strings containing a lead status.  I only want to count if the lead is qualified or nurture.  I have this expression:

```
Is Qualified = If('Lead'[Status] = OR("Qualified", "Nurture"),1,0)
```

But I am getting this error:

> DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text
>   with values of type True/False. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT
>   function to convert one of the values.

I'm new with DAX and haven't been able to fix this one.  Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OR() returns a boolean value. I assume 'Lead'[Status] is a text field, in which we will find some strings with the values "Qualified" or "Nurture". If this is the case you want to do the following:

```
IsQualified =
IF(
    'Lead'[Status] = "Qualified"
        || 'Lead'[Status] = "Nurture"
    ,1
    0
)
```

This is performing two tests, and combining them with a logical or ( || - the double pipe is DAX's or operator ).